# Cursor disappear at some place of a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

me with my team, have a problem with all textbox's cursor in our WPF app, at some place, the cursor don't appear.

Example, if i write "aaaaa"

1. a with no cursor
2. aa with cursor after aa
3. aaa no cursor
4. aaaa no cursor
5. aaaaa with cursor after aaaaa

Each time, it s at the same problem, we try to put default textbox with nothing in style / template / ... And we have the same.

We didn't loose focus of the textbox and we have try also this one :
[AutoComplete textbox and "Hide Pointer While Typing" in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734858/autocomplete-textbox-and-hide-pointer-while-typing-in-windows)

It s very strange.. Do someone ever had this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, if you wait for about 10 secs after typing aaa, no cursor ever blinks but if you type aaaa, the cursor blink appropriately? Try either a new project or new project on another computer. Maybe your .NetFramework is messed up.

Comment: Can you share your XAML for that text box?

Comment: Is your text bound to some property, which may actually change the value? because if this happens then as a result you will loose position of your coursor (caretIndex)

Comment: there is no problem with a new project, it comes from my projet. And time doesn't change anythings, i can wait 10 seconds on "aaa" and it will not appear, and if i write "aaaa" it won't appear too. But "aaaaa" will appear. I have tried nex textbox too, like that :  <TextBox x:Name="searchbox" Width="525" Height="250"></TextBox> and i have the same problem

Comment: My initial textbox is bound but there is the same problem with a void textbox :  <TextBox x:Name="searchbox" Width="525" Height="250"></TextBox>

Comment: If i have wrote "aaaaa" and i click on the middle of the word "aaa|aa" the cursor will not appear too. As i said, it s only at some place that it doesn't appear, and it's the same for all textbox of my app, it s very very strange ..

Comment: To clarify it, something in my projet disturb my textbox's cursor, but don't know what. My textboxs have focus, my textboxs's text bound property or not it's the same

Comment: also happened to me, no idea why this question got downvoted (perhaps missing some code, but still)

Answer (score 0):

Ok solve it with this :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633935/Customizing-the-Caret-of-a-WPF-TextBox

Just emulate a new caret and works fine now

Comment: emulating your own custom caret doesn't always work, it depends on the size of the text itself and the textbox's size, as well as other runtime parameters